# Cronbach alpha for non-Likert & Likert survey

Tags: spss, survey, cronbachs-alpha

I have a thesis ongoing and I have a survey that needs for reliability testing. I was advised to do a Cronbach's alpha test. My survey consists of two parts:

- **Part 1:** All questions have varying number of multiple choices with "Others:__" as a choice.
- **Part 2:** Likert scale questions. All are to be answered with a 4-rating key.

My question: How would you collect data for the Cronbach's alpha test in each part, and should there be any considerations that I need to know before conducting the calculations? I'm using SPSS by the way.

I tried searching information on how I will do a Cronbach's alpha test but all I'm seeing are "how to compute" for the test, not the "how would I ***collect*** data" for the test. I'm aware that the Part 1 and Part 2 will be having a different set of Cronbach's alpha test due to it's different type of question.

Please do enlighten me regarding this. Also, if you have any references (websites, free books, etc.) that could be of help regarding my inquiry, please do share it with me. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "Collect data"? I assume you are not talking about how you physically write and administer the survey? Are you asking how you may organize the data in something like an excel file for data analysis in SPSS?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. What I meant is that how do we do the cronbach's alpha especially in Part 1 since the choices there are not numbers unlike in Part 2.

Answer (score 1):

For part 2, you need all your Likert scale questions as columns and all your respondents as rows in SPSS data file. Then, you need to reverse code the reversed items, if there are any. Then, you can conduct reliability analyses on the items (using the reverse coded items in place of the original ones for the possible reversed items), Cronbach's alpha or McDonald's omega (the latter is generally recommended over alpha nowadays).

For Part 1, if there is one correct answer for each question out of the multiple choices, you can convert the replies as binary variables with values correct (1) - incorrect (0) and apply Cronbach's alpha (not sure about omega in case of binary data, but alpha should be fine).

If the multiple choice questions cannot be reconstructed as correct vs. incorrect, and are of the type

*Which of the following would you take with you to a desert island?*

A=canned food

B=sun lotion

C=a book

D=Other

and all choices are equally "good" and you're just interested in what choices your respondents made, you can't use Cronbach's alpha, and I don't know any reliability procedure that would work with this type of data.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sointu says, you cannot use Cronbach's alpha with multiple-choice (also called first-choice) data. Further, while it is acceptable to apply Cronbach's alpha to Likert scale data, there are alternatives such as Zumbo's Ordinal alpha (Gadermann, Guhn, & Zumbo, 2012; Zumbo, Gadermann, & Zeisser, 2007), which I cover in more detail [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589385/does-using-a-likert-scale-require-me-to-always-measure-the-internal-consistency/589586#589586). One way to assess the reliability of a scale consisting of Likert and multiple-choice data is to use item response theory (IRT). You would model Likert items using something like the graded response model (GRM)$^1$ and multiple-choice items with the nominal response model. I am not sure if `SPSS` can fit such a model, but I know for a fact you could use the `R` package `mirt`.

$^1$ The GRM is one of several IRT models that may be applied to ordered data. Others include the generalized partial credit model (GPCM; also see my previous response [here](https://Generalized%20Partial%20Credit%20Model%20(GPCM)) where I discuss this model). For more information on the various IRT models I highly recommend Thissen & Steinberg (1986).

**References**

Gadermann, A. M., Guhn, M., & Zumbo, B. D. (2012). Estimating ordinal reliability for Likert-type and ordinal item response data: A conceptual, empirical, and practical guide. Practical Assessment, Research, and Evaluation, 17(1), 3.

Thissen, D., & Steinberg, L. (1986). A taxonomy of item response models. Psychometrika, 51(4), 567-577.

Zumbo, B. D., Gadermann, A. M., & Zeisser, C. (2007). Ordinal versions of coefficients alpha and theta for Likert rating scales. Journal of modern applied statistical methods, 6(1), 4.

Comment: Thanks for the IRT suggestion, new information to me!